# DataGrid row selected trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have datagrid with hidden buttons, how to make button in row visible after row selection using Style.Triggers?

```
    <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">

                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="15" MinWidth="15" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Margin="0" Background="Gray">
                            <Button x:Name="CurrentButton" Content="{Binding number}" Visibility="Hidden"></Button>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not using `Trigger`, how about this:

Make `Item.IsSelected` property bound to `IsSelected` dependency property.
Then bind `Item.IsSelected` to `Button.Visibility` with a visibility converter.

Use `Trigger` when you have no access to editing the underlying class.